# Generate a random 2d array with random row length

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am trying to generate 2d random array similar to:

```
 array[random][random2]
 { 
   {1, 2},
   {6, 4},
   {-1, 5},
   {-2}
 }
```

the values in the array are also random, It may have -9 to -1 to 1 to 9 numbers.

Here's what i got:

```
public class gen2dArray {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      Random random = new Random();
      int n = 0;
      int max = 5, min = 1;

      n = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

      int maxRowCol = (int)Math.pow(2,n);

      int RandMaxRows = random.nextInt(maxRowCol);
      int RandMaxColums = random.nextInt(maxRowCol);


      int [][] array = new int [RandMaxRows][RandMaxColums];

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < random.nextInt(array[i].length)+1; j++) {
           array[i][j] = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
   }
}
```

Output 1:

```
 [
   [4, 4, 5, 0], 
   [2, 3, 0, 0]
 ]
```

Output 2:

```
[
   [5, 2, 1, 0, 0],
   [3, 4, 2, 0, 0],
   [3, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0], 
   [4, 3, 2, 0, 0]
 ]
```

There are few problems,

1. Some outputs are just [[]] or []

2.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
            at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300)
            at gen2dArray.main(gen2dArray.java:23)
```

3. Getting the zeros in the array. There should be no zeros.

Output one has to be like:

```
[
   [4, 4, 5],
   [2, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to see the zeros, you should avoid making your arrays to big :

```
  int [][] array = new int [RandMaxRows][];
  // Code
  array[value] = new int[random.nextInt(maxRowCol)];
```

This method should provide you an array of differents arrays of different sizes and just print out their real inputted values and not the `0` default values.

This is an example of an output :

```
[
    [2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 6, 9], 
    [1, 3, 4, 2], 
    [1, 4, 4, 2, 7, 6, 8], 
    [9, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3], 
    [4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 8]
]
```

Here is the modified code :

```
int [][] array = new int [random.nextInt(maxRowCol)][];

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         array[i] = new int[random.nextInt(maxRowCol)];
         for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
           array[i][j] = random.nextInt(9) + 1;
         }
      }
```

---

When `[]` is printed, it means your `Random` did return `0`.

A simple way to fix this is to add `1` to the concerned value and maybe decrease the MAX value from one also to keep the logic going.

Here is the code :

```
int maxRowCol = (int)Math.pow(2,n) - 1;
// Some code
int[][] array = new int [RandMaxRows + 1][];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate all these scenario by putting a System.out statement just before the array declaration.

```
System.out.println("RandMaxRows: " + RandMaxRows + "\tRandMaxColums: " + RandMaxColums);
```

---

> 1. Some outputs are just [[]] or []

This is happening when you are getting `RandMaxRows` as zero or both row and column are zero. We are using the `Random.nextInt(n)` for declaring the size of the array. The range of this method is `0` to `n-1`. So you can fix this by increment the outcome of the method.

> 2. n must be positive

This is happening when the `RandMaxColums` is zero. The input to the `random.nextInt(n)` must be greater then `0`, it throws the exception.

> 3. Getting the zeros in the array. There should be no zeros.

The inner for-loop should be like this.

```
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
```

You need iterate the array with it's length, for that any random number generation is not required. Use the current length and fill the array with randomly generated numbers.

---

Here is the work code for your problem:

```
public class gen2dArray {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int n = 0;
    int max = 5, min = 1;

    n = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    int maxRowCol = (int)Math.pow(2,n);

    int RandMaxRows = random.nextInt(maxRowCol);
    int RandMaxColums = random.nextInt(maxRowCol);

    System.out.println("RandMaxRows: " + RandMaxRows + "\tRandMaxColums: " + RandMaxColums);
    int [][] array = new int [RandMaxRows+1][RandMaxColums+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        int temp = random.nextInt(9);
        array[i][j] = temp + 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
  }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
RandMaxRows: 3  RandMaxColums: 3
[[1, 3, 3, 3], [2, 7, 6, 1], [5, 4, 4, 1], [6, 4, 6, 9]]
```